# Adding asymmetric error bars and boxplots in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, data-science, boxplot, errorbar

I have a Julia program that gives me data in the following form. For each point on X, I get a vector for the Y axis. I want to plot a boxplot for each X value using the vector of Y values. So I want the median to be the center of the boxplot and the error bars to basically be the first and the third quartile. Is there some inbuilt function in Julia which can help achieve this? If not, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer depends on what you have as an input.

I assume that you have `x` as a vector and `y` as a vector of vectors e.g. like this:

```
x = 1:5
y = [v .+ randn(100) for v in x]
```

Then use the StatsPlots.jl package and write:

```
boxplot(permutedims(x), y, legend=false)
```

(note that it is important that you pass the first argument as a 1-row matrix)

Answer (score 0):

If you have data as a `DataFrame` you can do:

```
using Plots, StatsPlots, DataFrames

data = DataFrame(x=repeat(1:3, 100))
data.y = randn(300) .+ data.x
boxplot(data.x, data.y)
```

Compared to the other answer - here the `x` is a vertical vector - in that case you get a single series.

[image]